# image dont show up(react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, jsx

im trying to put an image in my page but it wont show up.even though there are no errors here is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import img1 from './images/earth-icon.png';


export default function Navbar() {
    return(
        <div className="header">
            
            <h2 className="title">My Travel</h2>
             <img src={img1} alt="cam" />

        </div>
    )
}
```

thank you!

i tried to put the image in the public folder and try it like this:

```
import React from "react";


export default function Navbar() {
    return(
        <div className="header">
            
            <h2 className="title">My Travel</h2>
             <img src="./images/earth-icon.png" alt="cam" />

        </div>
    )
}
```

but its the same result.

Comment: `no errors` - where? is there anything in the devtools? in the network tab?

Answer (score 0):

If you put the image directly into the public folder, then the path of the image changes.
So, if your image is placed like this:

```
 - public
   - earth-icon.png
// other folders like src etc.
```

Instead of

```
<img src="./images/earth-icon.png" />
```

try

```
<img src="/earth-icon.png" />
```

This url will get translated to `https://example.com/earth-icon.png` which will point to your public folder.
If you need the same folder structure with images etc. Ensure that the image is placed under a `images` folder inside public. The you would be able to do:

```
<img src="/images/earth-icon.png" />
```

Note that `./` points to the current directory whereas just `/` points to the public folder